# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n!x^{n!}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n!x^{n!}}$. Should I look at this series as: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}({n!x^{(n-1)!})x^{n}}$? I am really confues here. In addition, any attempt to compute any kind of "lim sup" fails. I would appreciate your help in this.

Comment: Ratio Test should do it.  For intuition, note the obvious divergence if $|x|\ge 1$, and think of what happens for $|x|\lt 1$.

Comment: You can look at this as a power series where the powers of $x$ which are not factorials have zero coefficients: $0+1\cdot x+2\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3+0\cdot x^4+0\cdot x^5+6\cdot x^6$, then a limsup should make more sense.

Comment: The ratio test gives me zero, while another answer here says it is 1...

Comment: The Ratio Test shows that the limit of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$  is $0$ if $|x|\lt 1$, which implies (swift) convergence.

Comment: But $r$ is defined to be that limit. This is why I am so confused. I get what you all say, and it makes sense, but I don't understand why I can't get this "r" using a genuine test, as presented elsewhere.

Comment: Use the Ratio Test (or Root Test) on the whole expression, so $a_n=n! x^{n!}$.

Answer (score 4):

We could also use the ratio test.  Namely, the series converges when 
$$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)!x^{(n+1)!}}{n!x^{n!}}\right|<1
$$
In other words, after simplification, 
$$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|(n+1)x^{n(n!)}|<1
$$
So, in other words, you need $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(n+1)|x|^{n(n!)}<1$.
Using the continuity of log, we have that this limit is
$$
exp(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\ln (n+1)+n(n!)\ln |x|))
$$
Whenever $|x|\geq 1$, the limit diverges to infinity.  When $|x|<1$, the sum is a logarithm and a negative linear term which diverges to $-\infty$, so the series converges in this case.

Comment: $\frac{x^{(n+1)!}}{x^{n!}}=x^{nn!}\ne x^{n+1}$.  For $|x|<1$, we certainly have $x^{nn!}<x^{n+1}$ for $n\ge 2$, but we hadn't assumed $|x|<1$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks for the catch.  The proof still works after fixing my silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n$ is $1,$ hence this power series converges absolutely for $|x|<1.$ The same is true for any sub-sum, in particular for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n!x^{n!}.$ On the other hand the last series diverges for any $x$ with $|x|\ge 1.$ The desired radius of converge is therefore $1.$

Answer (score 1):

This power series has some powers of $x$ which have zero coefficient (when the exponent of $x$ is not a factorial).  This means that we should compute
$$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n!]{n!}
$$
(we're only looking at the terms with nonzero leading coefficient, the rest are zero and smaller, so they don't affect the limsup).

By including more terms, we can only increase the limsup (but it won't) so, 
$$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n!]{n!}\leq \limsup_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[m]{m}=1
$$

Now, adding the extra terms doesn't change the limsup because for any $m$, for all $n$ sufficiently large, $n!>m$.

Answer (score 1):

For each $ n\in \mathbb {N}$, let  $a_n=n$ if $n=k!$ for some  $k\in \mathbb {N} $ and $a_n=0$ otherwise. Then the radius of convergence of  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n!x^{n!}= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n $ is $$ \dfrac{1}{\limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n}}=\dfrac{1}{\lim \limits_{k}\sqrt[k!]{k!}}. $$ Since $\langle \sqrt[k!]{k!}\rangle $ is a sub sequence of $\langle \sqrt[n]{n}\rangle $ and $\lim\limits_{n}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$ we have that $\lim\limits_{k}\sqrt[k!]{k!}=1$. Therefore the radius of convergence is $1$.